# Add "Open with eclipse" in the windows explorer file submenu

Tags: eclipse, open-with, windows-explorer-integration

Sometimes you would like to **open a file directly inside eclipse** without having it included in any eclipse project.

On those cases it would be very handy to have the option Open with eclipse in the Windows explorer.

Please, do not misunderstand me, i do not want to open the explorer from within eclipse but otherwise around.For that there are other questions here.

Do you know how to add this submenu option to windows explorer?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to do this.

You can follow the instructions inside this article: 
https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/add-open-with-notepad-to-the-context-menu-for-all-files/

but instead of using notepad you use **the eclipse path**.

1. Navigate to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT*\shell
2. Right-click the shell key and choose New > Key. Name the new key *“Open with Eclipse.”*
3. Now, you’re going to create another new key inside that one. Right-click the new *Open with Eclipse* key and choose New > Key. Name the new key “command.”
4. With the new command key selected, in the right-hand pane, double-click the (Default) value to open it’s properties page.
5. In the “Value data” box, type the following text and then click “OK.”
6. **path2eclipse\eclipse.exe %1**

I have already tested and works without problem.